# EsentFileNotFoundException.FileNotFound exception when initializing RavenDb-Embedded

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm getting a very frustrating error when calling Initialize on the EmbeddableDocumentStore class.  This is a WPF application that is attempting to start or initialize a RavenDB database at c:\temp\ravenDb.

My code is:

```
EmbeddableDocumentStore _documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore()
{
    DataDirectory = @"C:\temp\RavenDb"
};

using (_documentStore.Initialize())
{

}
```

Fairly simple. The error occurs at the call to Initialize().  This is the full error:

```
Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentFileNotFoundException occurred
Message=File not found
Source=Esent.Interop
StackTrace:
    at Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.Api.Check(Int32 err) in C:\Work\ravendb\SharedLibs\Sources\managedesent-61618\EsentInterop\Api.cs:line 2736
InnerException:
```

What's frustrating is when I create a new WPF app and copy in the same code, it works correctly, and is able to initialize and create the base files.  Then, when I go back to my main WPF app - the db is now able to initialise (as the files have been created), but any Session.Query call results in the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
Message=segments.gen
Source=Lucene.Net
StackTrace:
   at Lucene.Net.Store.RAMDirectory.OpenInput(String name) in z:\Libs\lucene.net\src\core\Store\RAMDirectory.cs:line 301
InnerException:
```

Edit:
Full Code:
It's called from a Background Worker delegate:

```
private void RefreshGrid()
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);            
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    if (bw.IsBusy != true)
    {
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(_domainType);
    }
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = EventStoreInstance.Instance.GetAggregateRoots((Type)e.Argument);
}
```

Which then calls GetAggregateRoots:

```
//Called in class ctor:
_publisher = publisher;
_documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore()
{
    DataDirectory = _dataDir // is "C:\temp\RavenDb"
};

public List<AggregateRootModel> GetAggregateRoots(Type AggregrateRootType)
{
    using (_documentStore.Initialize())
    {
        using (var session = _documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            var aggregateRoots = session.Query<AggregateRootModel>()
                    .Where(p => p.Type == AggregrateRootType.AssemblyQualifiedName).ToList();
            return aggregateRoots;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you copy the code when creating a new WPF app and it works sounds to me like there may be something off in perhaps your .config file.. are you using a .config file to read any WPF settings by chance..?

Comment: No, there is nothing in my config file.  Also, when the initialise method blows up in my main WPF project, it has managed to create 3 folders: logs, system and temp.

Comment: can you show code from your main wpf if possible there is something that you might be over looking...

Comment: and your Initialize is that just an empty constructor..? or did you leave out the code..?

Comment: _documentStore.Initialize() doesn't accept any params.

Comment: should you be checking typeof(e.Argument) instead of Type

Comment: No, because e.Argument is a actually a Type.  Funny thing is, this all worked against Sql Server.

Comment: RavenDB must be .DLL issues it would have to be something with the DB Drivers

Comment: here is a site that I did a quick google search that may help you http://www.devcurry.com/ I will also keep searching and JSON.NET http://json.codeplex.com/discussions?size=2147483647 | http://www.alvinashcraft.com/tag/raven-db/

Comment: I Think that this site will help you out probably the best.. since I don't know how you are connecting to RavenDB let me know if this points you in the right direction. [Trying out RavenDB](http://cockneycoder.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/trying-out-ravendb/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are expected, they are handled internally inside RavenDB. You are seeing them because you are running in the debugger and stopping on any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks again Oren.  Also answered here: https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb/browse_thread/thread/1287f0e4f2883c3f